# Converting hours to timestamps

Tags: php

To convert a date to timestamp, I usually do this- strtotime ("2018-05-17 05:04:34) but now, I want to convert just hours (without date) e.g. 02:00:00 to timestamp. How do I do this?

Why I need this is to compare if a certain time is greater than the hour specified. This is what I am doing:

```
$reported = strtotime("2018-05-17 05:04:34");
$respons = strtotime("2018-05-17 17:04:34);
$response_time = $respons - $reported;
```

I want to be to check if $response_time is greater than 1 hour.

Comment: Are they of same date?

Comment: use substr and remove the first 11 characters of the string.

Comment: @Andreas The question is when there only time component and no date component, how to do the calculation.

Comment: It's the same. One hour is 3600 seconds

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe only I have understood your question correctly.

> *I want to convert just hours (without date) e.g. 02:00:00 to timestamp.*

There's no Date component here.

Okay, I assume they are of same date. If that's the case, just append an arbitrary date in front of the two to make the `strtotime()` function work:

```
$start = "05:04:34";
$end = "17:04:34";
$reported = strtotime("2018-05-17 " . $start);
$respons = strtotime("2018-05-17 " . $end);
$response_time = $respons - $reported;
if ($response_time > 3600)
  echo "More than hour!";
else
  echo "Less than hour!";
```

> **Note:** This doesn't work if the start time is 17:00 and end time is say, 08:00 - which occurs in the next day. You have to make sure if the start time is greater than end time, then you have to add one more day to the end time.

Comment: You mention no date part allowed in my comments, yet you do the same

Comment: you are appending arbritary dates

Comment: @delboy1978uk So? Only then `strtotime()` function works right? It won't work without date component. The OP just requires a code, which has to compare two times **without date component**.

Comment: so why criticise my solution? it's more elegant

Comment: @delboy1978uk No I am not criticising yours. You have completely deviated from what the OP wants. OP has two times. Start and End (I believe) and they want to get the difference, but there's no date in it.

Comment: How will this work? That means it will always be greater than 1 hour because the timestamp is usually in this format: 1526529874 and this is greater than 60.

Comment: @radioactive Sorry, I missed that part. It's supposed to be `3600` and also, the difference in milliseconds won't be more than `3600` if they are less than an hours time. Did you get it?

Comment: How did you get 60000?

Comment: @radioactive What I wrote before was right. It is seconds. I am reverting back to old version. I mistook it was in milliseconds.

Comment: @radioactive If the difference between two timestamps is less than 3600, then it's less than an hour.

Comment: dude check your maths, 60 seconds * 60 minutes is 3600

Comment: @delboy1978uk You are right, my Maths is weak! LoL. Sorry guys. Now corrected it perfectly.

Comment: I really don't understand, why a right answer has not been agreed by the rest of the community. Crazy really.

Answer (score 0):

There is `DateTime::diff`, which probably does what you need

https://secure.php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php

In your case that should be

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2018-05-17 05:04:34");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2018-05-17 17:04:34);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('H hours');
```

Answer (score 0):

Strtotime has no problem parsing a time without a date.
No need to fake a date which will come back and bite you with daylight savings.
I also added a check to see if the start/end is "reversed".

```
$start= "2018-05-17 05:04:34";
$end = "2018-05-17 17:04:34";

//Note that it's intentionally reversed
$diff = strtotime(substr($start,11))-strtotime(substr($end,11));

//If the calculation was reversed add one day in seconds
if($diff <0) $diff += 86400;

If($diff >3600){
    Echo "more than one hour";
}Else{
    Echo "less than one hour";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/g1jZH

Answer (score -1):

I like the DateTime class, give this a try:

```
<?php

$reported = new DateTime('2018-05-17 05:04:34');
$reported->modify('+2 hours');
$now = new DateTime();

echo $now < $reported ? 'less than 2 hours' : 'more than 2 hours';
```

See it here https://3v4l.org/T7BEL

See the DateTime class docs here http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: The question is when there only time component and no date component, how to do the calculation.